# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when array size declared with a variable

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I declare the array size with a variable, but not when I declare it with a number.

```
    static Student[] readFile(String filename) {
    .........

    LineNumberReader lnr = null;
    try {
        lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));
        lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        len = lnr.getLineNumber();
        lnr.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    len--; // discount the first line
    len = (len > 40) ? 40 : len;
    Student[] s = new Student[len]; <------- replacing len with a number resolves it

    try {
        f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));
        while ((line = f.readLine()) != null) {
            ......... 

            s[roll] = new Student(SID, marks); <--- Exception thrown here
            roll++;

            if (roll == 41) {
                f.close();
                throw new CustomException("41st Student!!");
            }
        }
        f.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CustomException e) {
        System.out.println("Too many students in the class!");
    }

    return s;
}
```

Can someone please explain me why Compiler is thinking I'm going out of bounds when Compiler itself doesn't know the bound, len?

Thanks!

Comment: Compiler does not give ArrayOutOfBounds...

Comment: And is there `never` more than 40 lines in a file?

Comment: Where have you declared `roll` and what initial value have you given it?

Comment: You've not exhausted all possibilities before coming to SO. Sorry for the downvote.

Comment: question without stackTrace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is a *RuntimeException*. If it occurs, then you're getting out of bounds for sure. 
Check whether `roll < len` before you do `s[roll] = new Student(SID, marks);`.

Also note that arrays are *zeor-based* in Java (and most languages). Hence, if you have an array of size `N`, then the indexes are from `0` to `N - 1` (total sum of `N`).

Answer (score 0):

```
s[roll] = new Student(SID, marks); <--- Exception thrown here
roll++;

if (roll == 41) {
    f.close();
    throw new CustomException("41st Student!!");
}
```

You declare your array with size `40`. That means you have access to `0-39`. Then you attempt to add a new `Student` object to `40` and `41`. This is evidenced by your `if` statement *expecting* a value of `41`.

Answer (score 0):

```
len = (len > 40) ? 40 : len;
```

Here you are setting the upper bound of array length to be 40. Incase your file contains more than 40 lines it will give an arrayOutofBound exception here:

```
 s[roll] = new Student(SID, marks); <--- Exception thrown here
```

So are you sure your files never will have more than 40 lines. If not so, then reverse the comparision as someone earlier pointed.

```
     len = (len > 40) ? len : 40;
```

Comment: There could be more than 40 lines, but in that case I'm immediately closing the file, ain't I?

Answer (score 0):

1. Where did you define the variable "len"? and which type has it? should be "int"
2. From where does the variable "roll" come frome? Which type has roll? should be "int", too

Make sure you use int values for the array index. Many simple types can be auto casted to int, but the result can be unexpected.

Make sure "roll" is never higher then your array size!

Remember an array index starts at zero! but the size by one.
Which ends up in:

```
String[] myArr = new String[5];
myArray.length == 5
myArray[0] == First entry
myArray[4] == Last entry!!!
```

Simple loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
```

Hope that helps, but normaly your step-debugger should answer questions like this for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
len = (len > 40) ? 40 : len;
```

There are 2 cases for values of len, both of which could lead to an out of bounds exception:

**a.** After the above statement executes, assume that len is initialized to value 40. Then the length of the array called s is 40.

```
s[roll] = new Student(SID, marks);
```

Assume that value of roll is  40. Then, you are assigning a value to index 40, i.e. s[40] = value, The valid range of indices is 0 to 39. Hence, the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown

**b.** Assume that len is less than 40.

```
s[roll] = new Student(SID, marks);
```

Here, as soon as you assign a value to the index greater than the size of len, you will run into an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

**Suggestion:** Add a test that the array size is within the permitted range, before assigning the value in the statement as follows:

```
if(roll < len)
{
    s[roll] = new Student(SID, marks); 
}
```